# Recorrer array de fechas en C#

Tags: c#

Buenas tardes, solicitando de su ayuda ya que tengo esta situación, de dos bases de datos diferentes tengo que obtener los días hábiles en un mes (L a V) y de otra obtener los días festivos del año, los cuales obtengo por medio de un ciclo `foreach`, el problema esta en que no encuentro la forma de pasar el valor del día festivo como una fecha hábil.

Es decir, del 1 al 14 de noviembre los días hábiles deberían verse así 01, 03, 04, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 14 quitando de la lista los sábados y domingos y el 02 que es considerado festivo en algunos lugares para lograrlo estoy haciendo lo siguente:

```
            foreach (string DiasHabilesCG in listHabiles)
            {
                foreach (string DiasFestivos in listFestivos)
                {
                    fechahabil1 = Convert.ToDateTime(fechahabil);
                    fechafestivo1 = Convert.ToDateTime(fechafestivo);
                    if (fechafestivo1 != fechahabil1)
                    {
                        if (fechafestivo1 == fechahabil1)
                        {
                            fechahabil1.AddDays(1);

                            Result = fechafestivo1.AddDays(1);
                            if (diafestivo1 == 6)
                            {
                                Result = fechafestivo1.AddDays(3);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ResultA = fechahabil1.AddDays(1);
                    fechahabilant = ResultA.ToString();
                }
                listHabiles.ToString();
            }
```

Cabe mencionar que para esto si el día festivo cae de lunes a jueves deberá sumar un día al día festivo es decir si 02 cae de lunes a jueves debe verse como 03 y si cae viernes deberá sumar 3 días es decir si el 02/11/2016 fuera viernes deberá mostrarse como 05/11/2016 que en ese caso sería lunes.

Comment: Para empezar, esto no tiene sentido: `if (fechafestivo1 != fechahabil1)
                    {
                        if (fechafestivo1 == fechahabil1)
                        {`.Primero preguntas si fechafestivo no es igual a fechahabil, y dentro de ese if preguntas si son iguales, lo que obviamente nunca será cierto.

Comment: Tal y como te dice Alberto no tiene ningún sentido el código. Como consejo te digo que uses el depurador. Es la herramienta más útil del desarrollador. Cuanto antes te acustumbres a usarlo mejor. Si lo hubieras usado te habrías dado cuenta de que el flujo no entra nunca en el segundo if.

Comment: De la base de datos estoy obteniendo una lista con los días hábiles de L a V y otra con los festivos, y con estos if lo que hago es comparar fechas en cada lista, si la fecha que esta en la lista donde se obtienen los días hábiles es diferente a la fecha del día festivo continua con el ciclo hasta que ambas fechas sean iguales, una vez que son iguales evalúa si el día es viernes y si es así suma 3 días mas y si la fecha es de lunes a jueves suma un día.

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que tanto listHabil como listFestivo sean listas, yo me olvidaría de los bucles for y lo haría con linq directamente:

```
var resultado = listHabil.Where(h => !listFestivo.Any(f => f == h))
```

Lo he puesto sin probar, solo como ejemplo de la sintaxis, pero creo que está bien. Si no te funciona dímelo y lo miro más a fondo.